# configure load balancer for wso2 api manager 3.2.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have configured WAF load balancer for three api gateway server and now I also have two analytics server, how should access to analytics dashborad? should I configured another load balancer for access to  analytics dashboard?

could you please guide me?

Comment: You can configure an LB to access the Analytics Dashboard, whereas you can open the IPs and Ports of both Analytics nodes to be accessed by the Gateway nodes individually (without any LBs in between). Both 7711 and 7611 are used to publish data to the Analytics node from the Gateway. You can have a look at this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/configure-apim-analytics/active-active/)

Comment: Thanks, but I mean was if we have two analytics active- active, we should acccess each dashborad individually in browser ? for example if one of them faild we should access to dashborad in other ip? so no LB between dashborads

Comment: No, if you have configured an LB to access the Analytics Dashboards, it is not required to access the portals individually. You can use the LB hostname to access the Dashboards. In case, if one Analytics Dashboard fails, the LB will route you to the other active Dashboard to access. Is that what you are expecting? Or have I misunderstood the requirement?

Comment: Thnaks , yes exactly

Comment: could you please check my following question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233937/how-to-configure-analytics-dashboard-for-loadbalancer @Athiththan