# How to configure analytics dashboard for loadbalancer

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I used wso2 api manager 3.2.0, my load balancer is in `172.25.129.72` and `69,70` is api manager server. When I configure dashboard to `69 or 70` server it works fine. but when I configure dashboard to load balancer, it throws following exception:

```
Exception occurred :sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target executing GET https://172.25.129.72/api/am/admin/v1/custom-urls/carbon.super
```

---

```
## Authentication configuration
auth.configs:
  type: apim
  ssoEnabled: true
  properties:
    adminScope: apim_analytics:admin_carbon.super
    allScopes: apim_analytics:admin apim_analytics:product_manager apim_analytics:api_developer apim_analytics:app_developer apim_analytics:devops_engineer apim_analytics:analytics_viewer apim_analytics:everyone openid apim:api_view apim:subscribe
    adminUsername: admin
    adminPassword: admin
    kmDcrUrl: https://172.25.129.72/client-registration/v0.17/register
    kmTokenUrlForRedirection: https://172.25.129.72/oauth2
    kmTokenUrl: https://172.25.129.72/oauth2
    kmUsername: admin
    kmPassword: admin
    portalAppContext: analytics-dashboard
    businessRulesAppContext : business-rules
    cacheTimeout: 30
    baseUrl: https://172.25.129.69:9643
    grantType: authorization_code
    publisherUrl: https://172.25.129.72
    devPortalUrl: https://172.25.129.72
    externalLogoutUrl: https://172.25.129.72/oidc/logout
```

Comment: Have you added the cert of lb to the analytics dashboard?

Comment: No I did not, is it required?